# How is the BalancedShard Algorithm of elasticsearch is implemented

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i am trying to learn how elastic search balances the shard allocation in the cluster.I tried to learn from the BalancedShard java implementation that is provided in the github but i am not able to get a hold on it.Could anyone give me an overview of how the BalancedShard algorithm works.

Github link : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.5.2/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/routing/allocation/allocator/BalancedShardsAllocator.java

Thanks in advance.